# Upload application from Visual Studio 2019 with PlatformIO

Tags: esp8266, visualstudio

How upload application from Visual Studio? I can’t find upload process from standard VS in documentation https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/ide/visualstudio.html

I hate VS Code.

Comment: Sorry but your question is far from both Arduino hardware and Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have final solution for uploading application from VS 2019.

1. Visual Studio have Tools > External Tools... where is possible add the PlatformIO command for uploading application `pio run -v -t upload`

[image: VS External Tools settings by PlatformIO]

1. After that is possible adding custom button to Toolbar [image]
2. Fantastic thing is, that during upload you can Stop the process [image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio Code, but I suppose the plugin works similar in Visual Studio. Look at the screenshot below.

[image: this]

In red rectangle you have "Project tasks options", where you can find "Upload" button. This will not work, if you have not set at least one environment in platformio.ini file – see the [documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf.html).
Example of the simple environment for Arduino Uno created in  platformio.ini file:

```
[env:uno]
platform = atmelavr
board = uno
framework = arduino
```

Comment: Of course, I use VS Code for Arduino, but this IDE is unworkable for my. My primary IDE for other development is full Visual Studio. There is support Resharper and many other features, that are on one place, and not in hundred extensions like in VS Code.
I hate VS Code

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed the note about your relationship to VSCode O:-) In Visual Studio I was using Visual Micro plugin to handle Arduino boards, but I suppose that is not what you wanted to hear...

Comment: It's ok, I edited my post:) PlatformIO is OpenSource,therefore is better for hobby users than Visual Micro.
I will try PlatformIO CLI `pio run -t upload`. It is not what I want, but maybe it will enough.